# Difference between OCCI and Instant Client package Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am a bit confused. I want to use Oracle Call Interface in C++ to interact with databases. This link: http://oradim.blogspot.co.uk/2009/07/getting-started-with-occi-windows.html says you need such packages:

- OCCI 11.1.0.6 (Visual C++9 (VS 2008)[Windows 32-bit])
- Instant Client Package - Basic: instantclient-basic-win32-11.1.0.6.0.zip
- Instant Client Package - SDK: instantclient-sdk-win32-11.1.0.6.0.zip

The 2nd and 3rd I have downloaded from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html.

My question is basically: What is the number 1 (OCCI 11.1.0.6) item on the list and where can I download it from? I have been looking for solution for this problem, but could not figure it out. Help appreciated. Is the first item separate from 2nd and 3rd items?

Comment: OCCI 11.1.0.6 was based back in 2009. Which version of Oracle are you using? They run parallel to the version of Oracle.

Comment: @Hector: I will check which version of Oracle(at my job). So you say OCCI libraries mentioned in that article should come with Oracle installation and they are different from the 2nd and 3rd items in my question? (Client Package Basic and Client package SDK)

Comment: @Hector: What is the difference between first and second items for example in my question? (OCCI vs clients)

Answer (score 0):

I googled 'occivc9win32_111060.zip' and found "OCCI Downloads - Oracle" :
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/occidownloads-083553.html

Maybe you have to register for the download.

Comment: do you know if that downloads you mentioned are available for Visual Studio 2005 also? I am using Visual Studio 2005. (needed to use for old project). And also are you sure the downloads on that link are different from the Oracle client package?(2nd and 3rd items in my question)